# Remove products from cart in django

Tags: django-views

I wrote a code to remove products from cart but instead it adds products to the cart.

Here's my **views.py**

```
def delete_cart(request, slug):
    products = get_object_or_404(Products, slug=slug)
    cart = Cart.objects.get(user = request.user, products=products)
    cart.delete()
    return redirect('cart')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('delete/cart/item/<slug:slug>/', views.delete_cart, name = 'delete-cart')
```

What is wrong with this codes?
Any suggestion will be reallly helpful.

Comment: Share the `urls.py`.

Comment: likely there is a collission with another path, hence you should share all the URL paths and the HTML part you are using to delete an item.

Comment: Yes, There was a collision between two url paths. Now, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70709658/remove-products-from-cart-in-django?noredirect=1#comment125002581_70709658), this was a clash between two paths: two paths that have certain possible paths in common. In that case, Django will pick the first one of the matching paths, hence the `delete_cart` view is never called.

You can further simplify the view logic to:

```
def delete_cart(request, slug):
    Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, products__slug=products).delete()
    return redirect('cart')
```

furthermore since this is a view that *alters* entities, this should be done through a POST or DELETE request, not a GET request, so you might want to restrict the view with the [**`@require_http_methods(…)`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods):

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

require_http_methods(['POST', 'DELETE'])
def delete_cart(request, slug):
    Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, products__slug=products).delete()
    return redirect('cart')
```

In that case you thus create a mini form that will make the POST request with:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete-cart' product.slug %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">remove from the cart</button>
</form>
```

with *`delete-cart`* the name of the path that refers to the `delete_cart` view.